# httpClient debugging order in subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I've got the following TS-method. When I set the two breakpoints #1 and #2 it first hits #1 for all my objects and after that it hits #2 for all my problems.

In my opintion that should be in another order.

````
  public getBuild(val) {
    let j_jobs: any;
    for (const project of val.projects) {
      for (const job of project.jobs) {
        this.httpService.get(job.url + 'api/json',
          {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Basic TOKENREMOVED'
            })
          })
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              j_jobs = data; //#2
            }
          );
      }
    }
    console.log(j_jobs); // #1
  }```

Can anybody tell me, why angular works like that?
````

Answer (score 0):

That's asynchronous coding.

In Javascript, you only have a single thread.

When you use asynchronous coding, such as Promises, Observables and AJAX, you ask your application to make something, then **do something while waiting for the process to finish**, and once the process is finished, **proceed with the callback**.

This allows you to create non-blocking processes. Imagine if you had to wait for your HTTP call to finish, and they took 10 seconds each ... Not very user-friendly !

In this case, you use Observables from RxJS, and make HTTP calls. So, it's asynchronous !